# Capistrano task is not running in cap deploy

Tags: java, ruby, capistrano

Using capistrano for the first time and trying to deploy a jar file in the remote host (or run a jar)

when I run `cap deploy` I see no error and looks succesfull. But, I neither see the jar running in remote host nor maven build and package!

following is my deploy.rb,

```
   namespace :deploy do
    task :deploy do
        puts "==================Building with Maven======================"
        run "cd #{deploy_to}/current"
        run "mvn clean package"
        run "java -jar #{deploy_to}/target/*dependencies.jar &"
    end
   end
```

Not sure if its the right way to do it? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  task :some_name do
     puts "==================Building with Maven======================"
     run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && mvn clean package"
     run "nohup java -jar #{deploy_to}/current/target/*dependencies.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
  end

  after "deploy", "some_name"
```

and run `cap deploy`

Comment: now, its working untill the build and packaging with maven. But, its not starting the jar!

Comment: did you try `run "cd #{deploy_to}/current/target && java -jar *dependencies.jar &"`

Comment: I did try. do I need to set java path and then  run?

Comment: edited the answer, it should be good now to run the jar file remotely